# Linux notify-send long message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notify-send

I am using `notify-send` on Ubuntu. Sometime the message is too long and the cutoff the beginner

```
...
message line 1
message line 2
```

How to deal if this and cut the end of the message? How much long can be the message to the `nofity-send`? (it depends of the screen?)

```
message line 1
message line 2
...
```